# Cloudfront + S3 permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

Some background. I'm using Rails + Carrierwave + S3 + Cloudfront.

I have a bucket and in the bucket there are many files. All the files are public. There is one file in particular. I can go to it on the S3 Console, select it, click on properties, and click on the link. It's a photo, so the photo will appear. I'm assuming that because I can do this, the photo has the correct public permissions.

I have a Cloudfront distribution pointing to this bucket. The Restrict Bucket Access is set to NO.

When I try to look at the photo through Cloudfront I get the error:

```
 <Error>
 <script/>
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
 <Message>Access Denied</Message>
 <RequestId>blah</RequestId>
 <HostId>
 blahblahblah
 </HostId>
 </Error>
```

This is driving me absolutely bonkers. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Hey, what type of permissions are you setting and using? Are you using bucket policies or setting ACL permissions for each and every file? It doesn't mean that if you can see the file that others will be able to see the file as well.

Comment: Hi Maxxie. We're using a gem called Carrierwave, and we have the setting config.fog_public = true.

Comment: @JPN what was the solution to this?